# storage space running out error?

Tags: google-play-store, internal-storage, insufficient-memory, file-management

So on my android tablet that I've had for about five months I'm getting an error in my notification bar that says storage space running out some system functions may not work. I don't know how to fix it. I first got this notification about a month ago and I managed to uninstall a bunch of apps and download clean master. It fixed the problem for a month. Then it did it again. So I used clean master and still it doesn't work. If I try to get a new app it says insufficient space on device or something like that. It won't let me download apps so don't tell me to download an app. I have downloaded many apps and had them on there at once. I uninstaled a bunch of them and it still won't let me download anything at all. Its not rooted so does any one happen to have a good you tube video or a good way that is fairly simple?